# Is i=++i; undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

This is undefined behavior, right? Double assignment in the same sequence point?

```
int i = 0;
i = ++i;
```

Comment: So it's valid in 17, but not in 11?

Comment: I think we need to reopen this. The duplicate was for post-increment. And the rules do differ on the UB. (I won't answer as per dupe hammer reopen etiquette).

Comment: @Bathsheba if you hypothetically had an answer, what would that answer be?

Comment: @NicolBolas: IIRC `i = ++i` is defined in C++11.

Comment: @Carbon: My answer waffled on about operator overloading which deviated from relevance.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Rather arrogant step no?

Comment: @Bathsheba: If that's the case, I'm sure you can find a duplicate that talks about pre-increment issues. There are plenty of such questions on this site.

Comment: In that hypothetical answer, was the conclusion that it was or was not defined?

Comment: I *think* `i = ++i;` is defined in C++11, but the "dupe" is to an expression that isn't defined until C++17.

Comment: There, dupe target changed to a Q that answers it all.  `i = ++i` is UB in C++98/03, and okay in C++11 and above.  It also covers all of the other cases.

Comment: Sorry folks but this needs an explicit answer since there is a lot of nonsense in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i = ++i;` is undefined in all C++ standards prior to C++11.

Note that cohorts of similar expressions using the postfix increments are not defined until C++17.

Both are defined if `++` is overloaded, which is a moot point here as the incrementee is a primitive.